# GridView left margin (Windows 8 C#/XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8

I'd like to add `GridView` to my page so that the first group has a `120px` left margin. If I set the left margin property on the `GridView` it does give me the right margin, but when I scroll the groups the groups are clipped to the left of this margin. Is there a way to set the `GridView` margin without clipping? What I did now is add a fake group that is empty. But now when I go to snapped view, I have a hard time to get this group to take up no space, even when the item template that I use in this fake group is just

```
<Grid></Grid>
```

I guess I could try to edit the GroupStyle and make the spacing between groups 0 (I would accept this as an answer as well) although this seems very ugly.

Comment: Sandra, please add your answer and I'll mark it as correct. I'm new to XAML (clearly:)

Comment: Sure thing, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2012's reference implementation of a Windows Store "Grid App" accomplishes this by the use of the Padding attribute on the GridView:

```
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
```

The snapped VisualState can be used to change the Padding value to something appropriate:

```
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemGridView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Padding">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```